# jQuery Mobile autocomplete JSON data

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I'm trying to get the jQuery Mobile autocomplete function working, but it only succeeds with external data. When i try to use my own JSON data it fails.

With the commented line in the js below it works fine with external data, but not with my own data.

js:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#mainPage", function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
    //url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
            url: "data/specs_search.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                q: $input.val()
            }           
  })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});
```

});

specs_search.php JSON output:

```
["Rota, AN, Spain","Rotan, TX, United States","Rothbury, MI, United States","Rothesay, NB, Canada","Rothsay, MN, United States","Rothschild, WI, United States","Rothville, MO, United States","Rothwell, QL, Australia","Rotonda West, FL, United States","Rotorua, BP, New Zealand","Rottenburg, BW, Germany","Rotterdam Junction, NY, United States","Rotterdam, ZH, Netherlands","Barcarrota, EX, Spain","Brothers, OR, United States","Crothersville, IN, United States","Croton Falls, NY, United States","Croton on Hudson, NY, United States","Croton, OH, United States","Crotone, CA, Italy"]
```

HTML:

```
<p>After you enter <strong>at least three characters</strong> the autocomplete function will show all possible matches.</p> 
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a specification..." data-filter-theme="b"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing dataType: jsonp with dataType: json.

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete send out unique callback id. You will need to wrap your json data with that.

```
jQuery191003769553452730179_1370870891109(["London Mills, IL, United States","London, AR, United States","London, EN, United Kingdom","London, KY, United States","London, OH, United States","London, ON, Canada","London, TX, United States","London, WV, United States","Londonderry, NH, United States","Londonderry, OH, United States","Londonderry, VT, United States","East london, EC, South Africa","New London, CT, United States","New London, IA, United States","New London, MN, United States","New London, MO, United States","New London, NC, United States","New London, NH, United States","New London, OH, United States","New London, PA, United States"]);
```